# Python inheritance and instantiation

Tags: python, scheme, interpreter, isinstance

I struggle to understand a point in the code by Peter Norvig, 'Even better Python Lisp interpreter', [here](http://norvig.com/lispy.py).

In eval function, aimed at parsing, he is doing the test isanstance(x,Symbol). Class Symbol is defined before, but it has no method, since it is declared with pass:

```
 class Symbol(str): pass
```

These lines build a symbol_table.

```
def Sym(s, symbol_table={}):
    "Find or create unique Symbol entry for str s in symbol table."
    if s not in symbol_table: symbol_table[s] = Symbol(s)
    return symbol_table[s]

_quote, _if, _set, _define, _lambda, _begin, _definemacro, = map(Sym, 
"quote   if   set!  define   lambda   begin   define-macro".split())

_quasiquote, _unquote, _unquotesplicing = map(Sym,
"quasiquote   unquote   unquote-splicing".split())
```

I don't understand why `Symbol(s)` is working, since no constructor for Symbol class has been defined. Afterwards, `eval` method checks whether the token is a Symbol the following way:

```
def eval(x, env=global_env):
     "Evaluate an expression in an environment."
      while True:
          if isa(x, Symbol):       # variable reference
              return env.find(x)[x]
          else: #other stuff
```

`isa(x,Symbol)` is a mystery. Here in code, should check whether token is a variable reference (that is x, with x that have been defined before). In my opinion, Symbol(s) here are a decoration for strings, in the initialization list built with

```
  _quote, _if, _set, _define, _lambda, _begin, _definemacro, = map(Sym, 
     "quote   if   set!  define   lambda   begin   define-macro".split())
```

Could you please explain based on your knowledge or reading of this code by P. Norvig or experience of Python? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like all other methods, `__init__` is inherited. `Symbol` inherits `str`'s `__init__`.

Update: Note further that `__init__` performs initialisation, not construction, and that initialisation code (with a slightly different effect) can also exist inside the class definition. This means that a valid object can exist without `__init__` even needing to be called.

Answer (score 2):

The class definition of Symbol is just that it's a subclass of `str`. In other words, it's a string for most intents and purposes.

```
>>> class Symbol(str): pass
... 
>>> x=Symbol('abc')
>>> x
'abc'
```

It is a new class though, which means it will be treated a little differently by the interpreter:

```
>>> x == 'abc' # __eq__ is inherited
True
>>> x is 'abc' # different memory location from 'abc'
False
>>> y='abc'
>>> y is 'abc'
True
```

`isa` is a (rather unnecessary) redefinition of `isinstance`, which just checks if the variable is an instance of `Symbol`:

```
>>> isa = isinstance
>>> isa('abc', Symbol)
False
>>> isa(x, Symbol)
True
```

Comment: `y is 'abc'` is actually not reliable; it depends on an implementation detail of CPython (short string optimization).

Comment: @larsmans yes, that's a good point, but regardless of whether or not `y is 'abc'`, `x is 'abc'` should *always* be False. That was the point I was trying to make.